# Deny direct access to folder except from specific URL

Tags: .htaccess

I was wondering if anyone knows if this is possible. Im trying to limit access to www.mydomain/PROJECT1 while making the same folder accessible through a colour box from www.mydomain/portfolio.php but im not having much luck.

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: I really don't understand why this is closed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Edited to include both 404 error and 301 redirect.*
I'm not sure if this is what you are going for, but I have limited direct access to certain folders in my site realm, but my scripts and files are able to access them.

In my htaccess file in the folder I wish to block I have the following:

```
RewriteEngine ON

RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://domain.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [R=404,L]
```

Replace domain.com with valid regex of allowed site address

This makes the browser display a 404 error (custom errors handled in a top level .htaccess). I chose this rather than a redirect, because unless checking server headers and such (hackers not site users) they wouldn't know the file is there. If you redirect back to a different page, especially on slower internet connections, the redirect is obvious.

```
RewriteEngine ON

RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://allowedURL\.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^.*$ http://mysite.com [R=301,L]
```

This will redirect from whatever they tried to access from that folder, to mysite.com

Comment: Also, this prevents hotlinking of any scripts, pictures, files, etc. in the folder containing the .htaccess.

Comment: cheers man, that worked like a charm. if i wanted it to redirect now what would i have to add to the code. For example if you go to http://cmcwebdesign.com/SSAS/ you get a 404 how can i make it redirect back to cmcwebdesign.com @ringhidb

Comment: @user1864284, I edited my original answer so code view would work.  Hope that helps, don't forget to select it as correct answer so it can help someone else.  Happy Coding.

Comment: Thanks again for your help :) I now have a new problem. The folder that contains the htaccess file also has code for Google docs viewer but Google docs cant access that folder now because of the restrictions. I've tried adding a new 'RewriteCond' for the Google docs view but that ended up showing the source from the 'RewriteRule ^.*$ http://mysite.com [R=301,L]' Any ideas on how i can fix this?

Comment: I'm not sure why @casperOne closed this as the post was provided with an accepted answer to the question, anyway, I'm not sure if you can edit your original post to include your new .htaccess, if not try emailing me or something.